# JSch is unable to find the private key using addIdentity when using HTTP URL

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, private-key

I have been using JSch to make SFTP connection to OpenSSH server and in this process when I am trying to add the privatekey as identity in the form of URI, the private key is not getting recognized.

When I try to run the URL from browsers, it is working properly.

I have tried all the way of using escape characters but did not work.

```
Session session = null;
ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

log.info(file.getOriginalFilename());
log.info(privatekey);
JSch jsch = new JSch();
jsch.addIdentity(this.privatekey);
log.info("identity added ");
session = jsch.getSession(username,hostname,portno);
log.info("Session Created");
session.setPassword(password);

Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setTimeout(60000);
session.connect();
log.info("session connected.....");
channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) session.openChannel("sftp");
log.info("Channel Opened.....");
log.info(channelSftp.toString());

channelSftp.setInputStream(System.in);
channelSftp.setOutputStream(System.out);
channelSftp.connect();
log.info("Channel connected.....");
//channelSftp.cd(destination);
log.info(file.getOriginalFilename());
channelSftp.put(file.getInputStream(), file.getOriginalFilename(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
channelSftp.put(file.getInputStream(),file.getOriginalFilename());


channelSftp.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

I expect the key has to be added using add identity but unfortunately I get the below error

> [https-jsse-nio-10443-exec-10] c.d.a.l.r.s.BlkCounterpartyServiceImpl   : Error Encountered is:com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http:/staging.fileserver.com/properties/xyz/xyz/xyz.ppk (No such file or directory).

The file is available in this location http://staging.fileserver.com/properties/xyz/xyz/xyz.ppk

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [`JSch.addIdentity` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#addIdentity-java.lang.String-) says:

> `prvkey` - the **file name** of the private key file. ...

*"file name"* = path to a *local file name*, not *HTTP URL*.

If you want to download a file from an **HTTP** server (what is a terrible idea from a security point of view), you have to code that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. Is there any way to make use of translate URI /URL to get added to addIdentity ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's your use case? Do you realize that downloading private key over unencrypted channel is very bad thing to do?